# ios: how to change date-picker display format?

Tags: ios, date-format, uidatepicker

I'm new in iOS.
How to change date-picker display format ?
My requirement is like below image.
Give idea or suggestion
Thanks

[image: i want date-picker like this short format]

Answer (score 3):

In Apple's documentation they specified that in UIDatePickerModeDate. The DatePicker displays months, days of the month, and years. This order items depends on your device local setting. you can check this documentation [Date Picker Description](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker)

if you want to same date picker then you could create your own picker.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with native UIDatePicker you need to use the custom one for e.g UIPickerview

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:"pass your string date"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EE, dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm a"]; // change format as per your needs
NSString * strTimestamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"your stirng%@",strTimestamp);
```

Comment: create new question instead of update exist question . because all answer given as per that question .

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 let todayDate:NSDate = NSDate()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"

 let str:String = dateFormatter.string(from: todayDate as Date)

 print("String is ----%@",str)
```

You can write as this Sender date of your date picker

```
 //let str: String = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
```

Out put

```
 String  is ----%@ 24 Apr 2017
```